# How to use .map() method to place values from one page to anther using data as coordinates for the next

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to take a data range of X and Y values and place a third column's value into another spreadsheet using the X and Y values as a cell range.  How can use `.map()` method to utilize the array for a series of tasks? Is my only real option to use a "for loop" which can be very slow to go through many rows of data?

I have tried and successfully utilized the "for loop" function to go one by one through one sheet find the values in each column and plot the third column of values in another sheet. However, the larger that list gets the slower the process

```
function testMap() {

  //Open Active Spreadsheet App
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //Capture sheets by name
  var sheetCoord = ss.getSheetByName('Coordinates');
  var sheetPlots = ss.getSheetByName('Plots');

  //Create last row and column variables
  var lR = sheetCoord.getLastRow();
  var lC = sheetCoord.getLastColumn();
  lR = lR-1;

  //Create array of all data
  var data = sheetCoord.getRange(2, 1, lR, lC).getValues();

  //Create variables for placement into proper sheet
  var x = data.map(function(f){ return f[0] });
  var y = data.map(function(f){ return f[1] });
  var v = data.map(function(f){ return f[2] });

  sheetPlots.getRange(y, x, lR, lC).setValues(v);

}
```

I expect this to map the values in the range than incrementally take each value of each range and plot the "v" cell value in the coordinates on the Plots sheet.  It just says

> "Cannot convert 6,2,1 to (class). (line 23, file "Code")".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to put values to the cells using the coordinates retrieved from the Spreadsheet.
- Column "A", "B" and "C" of the sheet of `Coordinates` are the column number, the row number and the value, respectively.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Issues:

- The issue of your script is to use `row` and `column` of `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` as the array. [The official document of `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns) says as follows.

> - row: Integer
>
>   - The starting row index of the range; row indexing starts with 1.
> - column: Integer
>
>   - The starting column index of the range; column indexing starts with 1.
> - numRows: Integer
>
>   - The number of rows to return.
> - numColumns: Integer
>
>   - The number of columns to return.

- In your case, it seems that the values are required to be put to the cell of each coordinate. By this, when the data is large, the process cost will become high.

  - Unfortunately, when `setValues` of Spreadsheet service is used, values are put to the continuous coordinates. This cannot be used for the situation that the values are put to the discrete coordinates.
  - For example, if your goal can use the situation that the cells are overwritten by the values including the empty values, `setValues()` can be used.

#### Solution:

In order to resolve above issues, I would like to propose to use the method of batchUpdate of Sheets API. When Sheets API is used, the values can be put to the cells of the discrete coordinates by one API call. And [from my experiment](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4), for putting values, when the data is large, Sheets API is faster than Spreadsheet service. From this situation, I proposed to use Sheets API.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please enable Sheets API at [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function testMap() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetCoord = ss.getSheetByName('Coordinates');
  var sheetPlots = ss.getSheetByName('Plots');
  var lR = sheetCoord.getLastRow();
  var lC = sheetCoord.getLastColumn();
  lR = lR-1;
  var data = sheetCoord.getRange(2, 1, lR, lC).getValues();

  // I modified below script.
  var sheetId = sheetPlots.getSheetId();
  var requests = data.map(function(e) {
    var obj = {};
    if (typeof e[2] == "string") obj.stringValue = e[2];
    if (typeof e[2] == "number") obj.numberValue = e[2];
    return {updateCells: {
      range: {sheetId: sheetId, startRowIndex: e[1] - 1, endRowIndex: e[1], startColumnIndex: e[0] - 1, endColumnIndex: e[0]},
      rows: [{values: [{userEnteredValue: obj}]}],
      fields: "userEnteredValue"
    }};
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
}
```

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)
- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm your situation.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike!  This works but scripting is very new to me and my eyes start to glaze at your edits.  It will take some time for me to understand most of your edits.

Comment: @Mike Loesch Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If you have any questions for my answer, please tell me.

Comment: Where can I go to get a better understanding or explanation of the language used like sheet id, like using { } and using a batch update as well as the general method in which you applied a very effective map () method?

Comment: @Mike Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether this is `a better understanding or explanation`, I have checked about `map()` and the method of batchUpdate at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) documents, respectively.

Comment: @Mike And about more sample scripts for `map()` and batchUpdate, I think that checking this Stackoverflow will help you understand. For example, those are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+spreadsheet+batchUpdate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+spreadsheet+sheets+api). If you have the issue for other situation, when you post it as new question, users can think of the solution. If these were not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

## Regarding the error

`y` and `x` are Arrays but the `getRange` method that uses four arguments require that each one of them are numbers, more specifically, integers. In other words, your code is passing the wrong data type for the first two arguments Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns

It's worth to note that `v` also is an Array (1D Array) but `setValues` requires a 2D Array.

## Regarding the use of Array.protoype.map

In a broad sense you are using it correctly. Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map, but not for the result that you are looking to get.

There are several ways to achieve that result

- Use "brute force" to set the cell values of each coordinate one at a time, perhaps by using a `for` statement, `Array.prototype.forEach` or other similar methods.
- Use "pseudo brute force", use Class RangeList
- Set all the values at once by creating a 2D Array and set all the values at once by using `setValues`

Comment: Thank you Ruben.  I had an additional question to your comment.  How do you do the last bullet point?

Comment: @MikeLoesch Use JavaScript to build a 2D Array of values. Bear in mind that should not be empty elements, for empty cells use empty strings `''` and that all the "rows" should be of the same size. One way is to create first a 2D array of the desired size by using `''` as the default value, then use the coordinates to put the value in the corresponding x, y coordinates (bear in mind that Array indexes are zero based).